# Bullet, changing btCylinderShape pivot point

Tags: bulletphysics

I'm using Bullet physics engine in a simulation.

I have a 3D node in my scene and i want to use a cylinder collision shape for it.(Yellow object)

Problem is that when i create a btCylinderShape , its Pivot point is in center of the cylinder,
but my 3D object has a different pivot point which is not in center (Its at bottom of cylinder for example)

So when i update my scene, collision shape doesn't match the 3D object as you can see in shot.

How can i change btCylinderShape pivot point to be in bottom instead of center?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use compound shape.

try search for: bullet physics center of mass

https://code.google.com/p/jbullet-jme/wiki/CenterOfMass

http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2209